# Home Button Press event not working in Jelly Bean

Tags: android

in my application i need to lock home button i want to use in Jelly Bean OS version i have used code which is in below url but using this when i press home button then open one popup and display 2 icon 1)Activity name and 2) Launcher but i want to do nothing in home button and stay in same activity, if anybody know then please help me.

https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/thread/1163

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to detect and/or intercept the HOME button from within an Android app. This is built into the system to prevent malicious apps that cannot be exited. or
Have u gone through this? [detect home button press](http://nisha113a5.blogspot.in/)

I m not the author , but came across it recently. hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Post ICS i.e. Android 4+, the overriding of the HomeButton has been removed for security reasons.

It is not a really good practice to not let the user navigate away from the application. But, since you are making a lock screen application, what you can do is declare the activity as a Launcher , so that when the HomeButton is pressed it will simply restart your application and remain there itself (the users would notice nothing but a slight flicker in the screen).